# Code block formatting issues with Bootstrap and Pandoc

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, markdown, pandoc, pre

I have a code block in a Pandoc markdown file designated as:

````
```python
for x in range(10):
  print('id is', x)
```
````

When I use the command

`pandoc example.md -s -o example.html`

I get the following output in a web page:

[image]

However, when I use a custom html template that uses Bootstrap CSS to generate the HTML, the indentation in the code block is wrong. The command

`pandoc example.md --template=custom.html -s -o example2.html`

produces the following output in the web page:

[image: example two]

Notice how the indentation in the second example is too large. This only happens when Bootstrap is used to style the code blocks. The indentation problem does not occur on the first line, only on the subsequent lines in the code block.

The template I'm using to generate the HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Example Pandoc HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    $if(quotes)$
      <style type="text/css">q { quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’"; }</style>
    $endif$

    $if(highlighting-css)$
      <style type="text/css">$highlighting-css$</style>
    $endif$

    $if(math)$
      $math$
    $endif$
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      $body$
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

How can I correctly format code blocks with Bootstrap and Pandoc when using a custom HTML template?

Comment: Presumably you would need to adjust/edit some CSS. But without the generated HTML and CSS you are using, It's hard to say what that would be.

Comment: @Waylan The only CSS I'm using is Bootstrap which was downloaded directly from the website. And the HTML is generated directly from Pandoc.

Comment: you can see what's going on e.g. with https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: @Waylan I updated my question to include the custom HTML template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un-indent `$body$` in your template, and it won't indent your code blocks.

```
    <div class="container">
$body$
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix! Works like a charm for pandoc 2.13.